# IE 11 error for d3 gauge dialler

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, d3.js

I have gauge chart. It works fine with firefox and chrome. But IE shows following error:

> *Unable to get property `setProperty` of undefined or null reference*

The code section is as follows:

```
this.body.append("svg:foreignObject")
    .attr("x", b.X)
    .attr("y", b.Y)
    .attr("id", b.ID)
    .attr("dy", b.DY)
    .attr("text-anchor",b.TEXT_ANCHOR)
    .attr("width", b.WIDTH)
    .attr("height", b.HEIGHT)
    .style("margin-top", b.MARG_TOP)
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .style("font-size", b.BODY.FS)
    .style("background", b.BODY.BG)
    .style("margin-top", b.BODY.MARG_TOP)        
    .style("font-weight", b.BODY.FW)
    .style("margin-left", b.BODY.MARG_LFT)
    .html(d);
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with the code. Any suggestion?

Comment: `foreignObject` [is not supported by IE 11 and below](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834675(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Mark, Thanks for your comment. Is there any other option for *foreignobject* that I can use in replace of ?